# Sort a xml file by value attribute php

Tags: php, xml

Okay im trying to get the 'TOP 5' of some xml files order by date value, hope you can help me, this is what i have for now

```
function getTopSongs( $n ){
  $result = array();
  $count = 0;
  foreach( glob("xml/*.xml") as $filename ) {
    if( $count < $n ){
      $xml = simplexml_load_file($filename) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
      array_push($result, $xml);
      $count++;
    }
  }
  return $result;
}
```

So now I call this and i Want the top 5 with the most news values, but cant sort it by date:

```
$top5 = getTopSongs(5);
```

This example for now just retunr the first 5 xml, but i dont have idea how order by date, thanks

Comment: Depends on your XML structure. Use an XPath expression on it to find the date you need, keep all these dates in a map of date to file name. After reading all files, sort the map by dates and return the top 5 ones.

Comment: to get the date you just need call $date = $xml[date] ,so if im recorring all: